# Populating a form field with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to pre populate a field on an embedded form. The field in question has the name property of "productname". I want to use the text content of an `h2` element on the same page the has the class `.djc_title` .
This code was working until recently. It appears that the embed code of my form is now referencing a different source for javascript and my code now gives me this error in the console.

> DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>      at fa.getText >>(http://www.example.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:2:13026)

And here is the offending code:

```
onFormReady: function() {
  var this_text = $(this).text();
  var h2c_djc_title = $('h2.djc_title').text().trim(this_text)
  var result = $('input[name="productname"]').val(h2c_djc_title);
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Why can't you just set the default in the HTML?

Comment: Is the embedded form in an iframe? If the main page and the iframe are in different domains, the main page can't manipulate the contents of the iframe.

Comment: 1. Replace `jQuery` for `$` for better readability. 2. Are you using an iframe?

Comment: possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Comment: Was the browser updated to a more recent version? There could have been an update to the browser's [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @ Thomas Juranek - I don't know what you mean. What default?

Comment: Also, I can't use $ because it conflicts with another framework in my CMS so I have to use " jQuery"

Comment: One of the pages in question is here> http://www.cirris.com/products/testers/item/1-easy-touch